# Next and previous buttons for ng-repeat modals

Tags: jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which when clicked produces a modal. I have been trying to add a next and previous button in the modal.

This is what I have been trying.

**JS**

```
$scope.nextGuide = function() {
    var currentIndex = $scope.thisIndex;
    var nextIndex = $scope.thisIndex + 1;
    var lastIndex = $scope.thisIndex - 1;
    jQuery('.dialog,' + '.' +currentIndex).removeClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('.dialog,' + '.' +nextIndex).addClass('active');
    }, 500);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modalSwitch">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
    <i ng-click="nextGuide()" class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently what is happening is the open modal will close, then it will re-open. I cannot figure out why the next modal will not open.

In the console, `console.log('.dialog,' + '.' +nextIndex);` prints out the correct jQuery selector.

Comment: Instead of closing and opening modals, why don't you instead change the content of the modals on clicking next and previous?

Comment: @callmekatootie I would do that, but I do not pass the array containing all of the objects to the individual modal. I'm not sure how I could do that with the scope of the variables I have within the modal... In the modal I only have access to that specific object.